# Do PHP frameworks such as Zend, symfony and CakePHP provide default protection against cross site scripting?

Tags: php, xss

ASP.NET MVC provides default protection against cross site scripting. Just wondering, if PHP frameworks do the same?

Answer (score 3):

- **Zend Framework** offers an [Escaper component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.escaper.introduction.html) to escape output and defend from XSS
- **Symfony** provides an [automatic output escaping feature](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#output-escaping)
- **CakePHP** before version 2.4 provided a [sanitization class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html)

I recommend you the following lectures for further information:

[Secure Application Development with Zend framework](http://static.zend.com/topics/Webinar-Zend-Secure-Application-Development-with-the-Zend-Framework.pdf)

Comment: Your symfony link points to the obsolete 1.x version's docs. Here's the current one: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#output-escaping